# NetBeans run java error -- run.xml

Tags: java, xml, netbeans

Recently I used Netbeans as my IDE to run `Window.java` file, However, when I run it, it shows `Can't find or fail to load main class ${fullscreen}`, then I open `/Users/yuanxiansen/Library/Caches/NetBeans/8.2/executor-snippets/run.xml:53`, the code is below.

```
<project name="{0} (run)" default="run" basedir=".">
    <target name="run">        
        <translate-classpath classpath="${classpath}" targetProperty="classpath-translated" />
        <property name="run.jvmargs" value="" />
        <property name="work.dir" value="${basedir}"/>
        <property name="application.args" value="" />
        <property name="java.failonerror" value="true"/>
        <java classpath="${classpath-translated}" classname="${fullscreen}" dir="${work.dir}" jvm="${platform.java}" fork="true" failonerror="${java.failonerror}">//this line has error!!!!
            <jvmarg value="-Dfile.encoding=${encoding}"/>
            <redirector inputencoding="${encoding}" outputencoding="${encoding}" errorencoding="${encoding}"/>
            <jvmarg line="${run.jvmargs}" />
            <arg line="${application.args}" />
            <syspropertyset>
                <propertyref prefix="run-sys-prop."/>
                <mapper from="run-sys-prop.*" to="*" type="glob"/>
            </syspropertyset>
        </java>
    </target>
</project>
```

Plus, this is my file tree

[image]

Since I was already familiar with IDEA but it seems a little trickle for NetBeans. Could someone tell me how to configure NetBeans and enable it to run correctly?

Comment: Have you changed this file ? I haven't use Netbeans since a while, but all should be fine in order to launch an application without any change...

Comment: I mis-changed `classname="${fullscreen}"`, but I forgot its original value.

Comment: try to regenerate the project, or look at the configuration of another one. the values seems associated to a ResourceBundle according to the format of the paameters

Comment: I solved it by copying my code in another java file and then changed the package name, so finally, it run smoothly, still thank you very much!